# How to create the correct prompt in LLM? Example: GPT, MPT and Falcon etc

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Input:
[image]

Output:

[image]

My python code for performing the task

```py
    skill_descriptions = [
    "Python programming",
    "Data analysis",
    "Machine learning",
    "Web development",
    # Add more skill descriptions as needed 
]

    input_texts = [
    "I am proficient in Python programming and data analysis.",
    "Looking for a job in machine learning.",
    "Experienced web developer specializing in front-end development."
    # Add more input texts as needed
]

selected_skills = []

    for input_text in input_texts:
    prompt = (
        f"What is the most suitable skill from the list of skill descriptions for each given input text?.\n\nInput Text: {input_text}\n\nSkill Descriptions:\n"
        + "\n".join(skill_descriptions)
        + "\n\nSelected Skill:"
    )

    payload = json.dumps(
        {
            "model_name": "mpt",  # Replace with the desired model name
            "prompt": prompt,
            "n_tokens_limit": 512,
            "n": 1,
            "temperature": 0.1,
        }
    )

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

    response = requests.request(
        "POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False
    )

    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    print(response_json)
    selected_skill = response_json
    selected_skills.append(selected_skill)

print(selected_skills)
```

What should I do or change the prompt so that the right skill from the list of skill_descriptions gets matched with each input text?